# If I'm already using Modernizr, will I then even need HTML5 Shiv?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, modernizr

1) If I'm already using Modernizr, will I then even need HTML5 Shiv to enable HTML5 tag support for IE?

2) Is HTML5 Shiv only for IE, or for all browser who don't have native HTML 5 support? Like older versions of Firefox, Safari, Chrome, etc?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> 1) If I'm already using Modernizer then even will I need HTML5 Shiv to
>   enable HTML5 tag supports for IE.

You don't need to separately include [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/), because Modernizr includes it:

> As of Modernizr 1.5, this script is identical to what is used in the
>   popular html5shim/html5shiv library.

http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie

---

> 2) and is HTML5 Shiv only for IE or for all browser who don't have
>   native HTML 5 support. like older version of Firefox, Safari, Chrome
>   etc.

It's only for Internet Explorer.

Older versions of other browsers don't need it: http://caniuse.com/html5semantic

And the recommended snippet to include it is:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Which will only ever run for IE less than 9.

Comment: Great and quick answer as i expected. So only IE was the show stopper.

Comment: You mean when I download custom Modernizer I should keep marked the *HTML5 Shim/IEPP* checkbox on this page http://www.modernizr.com/download/

Comment: Yes, you must keep that ticked if you want html5shiv to be included.